# T-SQL Is there an abbreviated version of CASE WHEN..?

Tags: t-sql, case, isnull

With years of handling special cases in some of my queries, I'm curious if there is a simlified version of the CASE logic below:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN AverageRate < 0.1 THEN 0 ELSE AverageRate END AS [AverageRate]
FROM AdventureWorks.Sales.CurrencyRate
```

Ideally, it would behave very similarly to ISNULL, but allows for an additional input for the conditional statement.

I know it would be relatively easy to roll my own function, but I was wondering if there was something built in that I could tap.

Thanks.

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server 2012 is likely to introduce the [IIF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) function. I say 'likely' because we can't be sure until the release version is shipped. De-facto, it is supported in current RC's.

As for the earlier versions of SQL Server, there are no such built-in shorthand approaches.

Comment: Thanks for the info, Yuriy. I just spun up a few 2012 RC servers here so I'll keep an eye out for it on RTM.

Answer (score 0):

I've been around sql server quite a few years and haven't come across any shorter clause to  perform conditional check.